# Download file by url which contains param

Tags: android, download, httpconnection

I am a newbie to the Android platform, I am creating an android application which downloads files from the internet:
I found some examples on the internet regarding download file but all of them are download file from url as

> *http/https:sample_address/file_to_download.xyz*

. But my application need to download file from url as *

> http/https:sample_address/file_to_download.xyz?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=admin%2F20221025%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221025T093017Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%2220_2022-24-10.apk%22&X-Amz-Signature=4968bbf4093b5d1fa6f0368ac1cfa445480bc301b132e740a7cf38fe81d9d2b5

- 

Below are lines of code that I use to download files but it doesn't work

```
private fun downloadUpdate(apkPath: String, versionCode: Int) =
    serviceScope.launch {
        try {
            //set the path where we want to save the file
            //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
            //sd card.
            val apkFileName = "${versionCode}.apk"
            val appDataRoot = File(AppConstants.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PATCH)
            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.
            val file = File(appDataRoot, apkFileName)
            GLog.d(UpdateSoftwareViewModel.TAG, "AppUpdate apkFileName =${apkFileName}")
            GLog.d(UpdateSoftwareViewModel.TAG, "AppUpdate apkFileName exist =${file.exists()}")
            var updatedApkExist = file.exists()
            if (!updatedApkExist) {
                //create the new connection
                /*https:sample_address/file_to_download.xyz?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=admin%2F20221025%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221025T093017Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%2220_2022-24-10.apk%22&X-Amz-Signature=4968bbf4093b5d1fa6f0368ac1cfa445480bc301b132e740a7cf38fe81d9d2b5*/
                val pathSplit = apkPath.split("?")
                val connectionParams = pathSplit[1].split("&")
                val urlConnection = URL(pathSplit[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connectionParams.forEach {
                    val param = it.split("=")
                    GLog.d(TAG,"setRequestProperty ${param[0]} = ${param[1]}")
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty(param[0],param[1])
                }

                //set up some things on the connection
                urlConnection.requestMethod = "GET"
                urlConnection.doOutput = true
                //and connect!
                urlConnection.connect()
                //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
                val fileOutput = FileOutputStream(file)
                //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
                val inputStream = urlConnection.inputStream //Exception HERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:sample_address/file_to_download.xyz
                //this is the total size of the file
                val totalSize: Int = urlConnection.contentLength
                //variable to store total downloaded bytes
                var downloadedSize = 0
                //create a buffer...
                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                var bufferLength: Int //used to store a temporary size of the buffer
                //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
                while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bufferLength = it } > 0 && isActive) {
                    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
                    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength
                    //Send message update progress
                    val message = Message()
                    message.what = AppConstants.DOWN_LOAD_PROGRESS
                    message.arg1 = downloadedSize / totalSize
                    downloadHandlerList.forEach {
                        it.sendMessage(message)
                    }
                }
                //close the output stream when done
                fileOutput.close()
                updatedApkExist = downloadedSize == totalSize
            }
            if (updatedApkExist) {
                GLog.d(VerifyUserViewModel.TAG, "AppUpdate do install")
                installApplication(this@UpdateSoftwareService, file.absolutePath)
            }
            //Stop service when the download task is done
            stopSelf()
        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            GLog.d(UpdateSoftwareViewModel.TAG, "MalformedURLException exception ${e.message}")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            GLog.d(UpdateSoftwareViewModel.TAG, "IOException exception ${e.message}")
        }
    }
```

I don't want to use DownloadManager because I want to publish the progress of the download process.

Could you help me to download the file from the internet in url format as

> https:sample_address/file_to_download.xyz?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=admin%2F20221025%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221025T093017Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%2220_2022-24-10.apk%22&X-Amz-Signature=4968bbf4093b5d1fa6f0368ac1cfa445480bc301b132e740a7cf38fe81d9d2b5

Comment: Will the parameters change the content of your file to download or will it remain the same?

Comment: With or without parameters should not make a difference. An url is an url. Please explain first why you think its different.

Comment: And using DownloadManager you can also display progress.